# Minimax python returns a win when it won't win

Tags: python, python-3.x, minimax

I am making a minimax in python, using 3 functions: max, min, and minimax. It seems to be working, but every win condition starts with `['X','X','X',....]`
(`...` being any other X & O combination)
Why does this happen?

Program Parts:

Minimax

```
def minimax(game_state):
    moves = game_state.get_possible_moves()
    print('possible moves are:'+str(moves))
    best_move = None
    best_score = -2
    for move in moves:
        clone = game_state.get_next_state(move, True)
        score = max_play(clone)
        if score > best_score:
            best_move = move
            best_score = score
    return ['best move'+str(best_move), 'best score'+str(best_score)]
```

Max_play

```
def max_play(game_state):
    if game_state.is_gameover():
        return evals(game_state)
    moves = game_state.get_possible_moves()
    best_score = -2 #not possible
    best_move = None
    for move in moves:
        clone = game_state.get_next_state(move, True)
        score = min_play(clone)
        if score > best_score:
            best_move = move
            best_score = score
```

Min_play

```
def min_play(game_state):
    if game_state.is_gameover():
        return evals(game_state)
    moves = game_state.get_possible_moves()
    best_move = None
    best_score = 2 #not possible
    for move in moves:
        clone = game_state.get_next_state(move, False)
        score = max_play(clone)
        if score < best_score:
            best_move = move
            best_score = score
    return best_score
```

Class and Evaluation

```
class GameState:
    def __init__(self,board):
        self.board = board
        self.character = 'X'
        self.winning_combos = [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8],[0,3,6],[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[0,4,8],[2,4,8]]
    def is_gameover(self):
        if self.board.count('X') + self.board.count('O') == 9:
            return True
        for combo in self.winning_combos:
            if (self.board[combo[0]] == 'X' and self.board[combo[1]] == 'X' and self.board[combo[2]] == 'X') or (self.board[combo[0]] == 'O' and self.board[
                return True
        return False
    def get_possible_moves(self):
        squares = []
        for square in self.board:
            if square != 'X' and square != 'O':
                squares.append(int(square))
        return squares
    def get_next_state(self, move, computer_turn):
        copy = list(self.board)
        if computer_turn:
            copy[move] = 'X'
        else:
            copy[move] = 'O'
        return GameState(copy)

def evals(game_state):
    for combo in [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8],[0,3,6],[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[0,4,8],[2,4,8]]:
        if game_state.board[combo[0]] == 'X' and game_state.board[combo[1]] == 'X' and game_state.board[combo[2]] == 'X':
            print('WIN',game_state.board)
            return 1
        elif game_state.board[combo[0]] == 'O' and game_state.board[combo[1]] == 'O' and game_state.board[combo[2]] == 'O':
            print('LOSS',game_state.board)
            return -1
        else:
            return 0
```

Comment: Please look into creating a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). More often than not, _you'll_ discover the problem this way.

Comment: your code is too long, don't read it. Use `print()` to see values in variables and check which part of code is executed.

Comment: Please provide your debugging efforts so far.  Use basic [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) principles